# Deep link for redirecting an URL

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an android application which implemented Forgot Password functionality.If user forgot his password, an e-mail will send to him and opening this email will direct the user to password resetting page.
After resetting, my landing redirect URL is in the format **https://sample.com/Home**

From this landing page I want the user to redirect to mobile app.

Following is my manifest.xml for deep linking

```
  <data
      android:host="sample.com"
      android:path="/Home"
      android:scheme="https"/>
```

But the above implementation did not redirect to mobile app on resetting password.

I have mailed the URL directly to the Gmail and on clicking, get a prompt whether to open app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you include those categories in your intent-filter?

```
<intent-filter> 
    ...
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yes . I did.Already added   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> in manifest.xml